# Reset CirclePageIndicator library

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I wanted to have image lazy Loading in my ListView. I put the images in a [ViewPager](https://github.com/chiuki/android-swipe-image-viewer/blob/master/src/com/sqisland/android/swipe_image_viewer/MainActivity.java), and then also set a [CirclePageIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) for ViewPager:

```
public void fetchDrawableOnThread(final ViewPager viewPager, final CirclePageIndicator indicator) {     

        final Handler handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message message) {
                ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter((Drawable[]) message.obj);
                viewPager.setAdapter(adapter); 
                indicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        };

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() { 

                Drawable[] drawables = fetchDrawables();

                Message message = handler.obtainMessage(1, drawables);
                handler.sendMessage(message);
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
```

This is my custom adapter class in the main Activity:

```
private class MultiAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {


    public MultiAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> mStrings) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_main, mStrings);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row;

        if (convertView == null)  {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_main, parent, false);
        } else
            row = convertView;

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) row.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        CirclePageIndicator indicator = (CirclePageIndicator)row.findViewById(R.id.indicator);

        if(scroll_is_idle)
            drawableMng.fetchDrawableOnThread(viewPager, indicator); 
        else {
            viewPager.setAdapter(null);
        }

        return row;
    }
}
```

In my getView method, I want to `set viewPager adapter to null, when the scroll is not in idle mode` and that makes the problem in PageIndicator library (nullPointerException). Do you know how can I reset the PageIndicator to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that this logic may not be that good:

```
if(scroll_is_idle)
      drawableMng.fetchDrawableOnThread(viewPager, indicator); 
else 
      viewPager.setAdapter(null);
```

But by the way it made a problem in onDraw method in [ViewPageIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) library, with a nullPoniterException.

I solved my problem by editing onDraw and add `mViewPager.getAdapter() == null` to the condition:

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (mViewPager == null || mViewPager.getAdapter() == null) {
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Can it be added to the main library ? @JakeWharton